# Leaderboard in unity with playfab

Tags: unity-game-engine, leaderboard, playfab

in my case the user logs in with a username and password, I would like to know how I can make the leaderboard leave that username and not the user id, can anyone help me?

I have seen videos where the display name is used, but there is no way to directly take the username and that's it?I have seen videos where the display name is used, but there is no way to directly take the username and already

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.